# Android datepicker year field changed in ICS

Tags: android, datepicker, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I was using DatePicker component in my app to choose a day/month/year

Now that my phone is updated to ICS, I discovered that the year field is replace by a full calendar. Is there a way to go back to the 3 columns with day / month / year?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `android:calendarViewShown="false"` on your `<DatePicker>` in your layout.